# Creating keys/names from interfaces to avoid strings

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, expression-trees

There are many APIs that require some kind of a `string` key/name. I usually try to avoid using raw `string`s and prefer to use helpers that can create them for me.

One such a tool is intended to be used with my [`FeatureService`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220938/toggle-any-application-feature-on-or-off) that requries feature names as `string`s.

#### Usage examples

In order to use it, I need a new set of extensions that provide alternative APIs / overloads:

```
public static class FeatureServiceExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> ExecuteAsync<TScope, T>
    (
        this FeatureService features,
        INamespace<TScope> scope,
        Expression<Func<TScope, T>> feature,
        Func<Task<T>> body
    ) where TScope : INamespace
    {
        return features.ExecuteAsync(FeatureKey<TScope>.Create(feature), body, default);
    }

    public static FeatureService Configure<TScope, T>
    (
        this FeatureService features,
        INamespace<TScope> scope,
        Expression<Func<TScope, T>> feature,
        Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure
    ) where TScope : INamespace
    {
        return features.Configure(FeatureKey<TScope>.Create(feature), configure);
    }
}
```

#### Generic type helper

The first interface you see there is actually a *trick* to provide the `TScope` to the method so I don't have to do it explicitly on the `Execute` method. This is all it is:

```
// ReSharper disable once UnusedTypeParameter - 'T'  is required.
public interface INamespace<out T> where T : INamespace { }

public static class Use<T> where T : INamespace
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public static INamespace<T> Namespace => default;
}

// Protects the user form using an unsupported interface by mistake.
public interface INamespace { }
```

#### Classic names vs helper

It allows me to rewrite this

> ```
> _features.Configure(nameof(SayHallo), o => o ^ Enabled);
> ```

which uses the feature name `SayHallo` as

```
_features.Configure(Use<IDemoFeature>.Namespace, x => x.SayHallo, o => o ^ Enabled);
```

which will now use `Demo.SayHallo`.

#### Interface as name provider

The names are built from an interface. The property's type doesn't matter as it won't be used actually anywhere here. It's all about not having `string` or even a `const`.

```
public interface IDemoFeature : INamespace
{
    object SayHallo { get; }
}
```

by the `FeatureKey` helper

```
public static class FeatureKey<TNamespace>
{
    private static readonly IKeyFactory DefaultKeyFactory = new TypedKeyFactoryAttribute("Feature");

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static string Create(LambdaExpression keyExpression)
    {
        var keyFactory = keyExpression.ToMemberExpression().Member.GetCustomAttribute<KeyFactoryAttribute>(inherit: true) ?? DefaultKeyFactory;
        return keyFactory.CreateKey(keyExpression);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static string Create<TMember>(Expression<Func<TNamespace, TMember>> selectMember)
    {
        return Create((LambdaExpression)selectMember);
    }
}
```

#### Naming conventions with attribute factories

It creates the name by using `IKeyFactory`. Currently there are two implementations. The `SimpleKeyFactory` uses only the member name and the `TypedKeyFactory` also the type name which is the default for the `FeatureKey`.

```
public interface IKeyFactory
{
    string CreateKey(LambdaExpression keyExpression);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public abstract class KeyFactoryAttribute : Attribute, IKeyFactory
{
    public abstract string CreateKey(LambdaExpression keyExpression);
}

public class SimpleKeyFactoryAttribute : KeyFactoryAttribute
{
    public override string CreateKey(LambdaExpression keyExpression)
    {
        return keyExpression.ToMemberExpression().Member.Name;
    }
}

public class TypedKeyFactoryAttribute : KeyFactoryAttribute
{
    private readonly string _suffix;

    public TypedKeyFactoryAttribute(string suffix)
    {
        _suffix = suffix;
    }

    public override string CreateKey(LambdaExpression keyExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = keyExpression.ToMemberExpression();
        return $"{GetScopeName(memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType)}.{memberExpression.Member.Name}";
    }

    private string GetScopeName(Type type) => Regex.Replace(type.ToPrettyString(), $"^I|{_suffix}$", string.Empty);
}
```

I can change this behavior by decorating a property with a different attribute like:

```
public interface IDemoFeature : INamespace
{
    [SimpleyKeyFactory]
    object SayHallo { get; }
}
```

I'm not decorating the class because chaning conventions is a rare operation so I think it's ok to use it only for the exceptional cases.

---

I often use the `MemberExpression` so the above code uses one more convenience extension that makes sure the expression is actually a member-expression.

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    [NotNull]
    public static MemberExpression ToMemberExpression(this LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    {
        return
            lambdaExpression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression
                ? memberExpression
                : throw DynamicException.Create
                (
                    $"NotMemberExpression",
                    $"Expression '{lambdaExpression}' is not a member-expression."
                );
    }
}
```

---

#### Questions

- Is this helper intuitive and easy to use?
- Is it easy to extend and customize?
- Is it missing any *obvious* features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Review

> Is this helper intuitive and easy to use?

---

In the code snipper below:

- `INamespace<TScope> scope` seems unused?

> ```
> public static FeatureService Configure<TScope, T>
>     (
>         this FeatureService features,
>         INamespace<TScope> scope,
>         Expression<Func<TScope, T>> feature,
>         Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure
>     ) where TScope : INamespace
>     {
>         return features.Configure(FeatureKey<TScope>.Create(feature), configure);
>     }
> ```

---

About that generic type helper, I'm just missing how this helps you out. Could you provide an example why `INamespace`, `INamespace<T>` and `Use<T>` are required? To me, atleast, it is not *intuitive*.

> ```
> public static class Use<T> where T : INamespace
> {
>     [DebuggerNonUserCode]
>     public static INamespace<T> Namespace => default;
> }
> ```

---

miscellaneous, off-topic

- hard-coded string detected :-p

  > ```
  > private static readonly IKeyFactory DefaultKeyFactory = new
  > TypedKeyFactoryAttribute("Feature");
  > ```
- resharper, this day and age .. really? :)

  > ```
  > // ReSharper disable once UnusedTypeParameter - 'T'  is required.
  > public interface INamespace<out T> where T : INamespace { }
  > ```
- good usage of `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` and `DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute`

---

Comment: I use that _namespace_ helper because e.g. `Configure` requires two generic parameters `<TScope, T>`, I need the first one to select `x => x.SayHallo`, without the helper I would always need to specify them both explicitly, `Configure<IDemoFeature, object>`, with the helper I can avoid this and let the compiler figure out the `T`.

Comment: haha, what do you mean with _resharper, this day and age_? You're right, `scope` is not used, its only purpose is to _deliver_ `TScope` so that I can use it with the `Expression`

Comment: @t3chb0t the latest VS comes with much of the interesting features 'inspired' by resharper and has much better performance.

Comment: I prefer JetBrains Rider, much faster than VS, even the latest VS cannot comepete with Rider. I use VS only sporadically these days.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original API is really not as intuitive as I thought. I simplified it by replacing this

> ```
> public static FeatureService Configure<TScope, T>
> (
>     this FeatureService features,
>     INamespace<TScope> scope,
>     Expression<Func<TScope, T>> feature,
>     Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure
> ) where TScope : INamespace
> {
>     return features.Configure(FeatureKey<TScope>.Create(feature), configure);
> }
> ```

with

```
public static FeatureService Configure
(
    this FeatureService features,
    string name,
    Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure
)
{
    return features.Configure(name, configure);
}
```

where I'm using just the `string`. The creation of the `name` is entirely up to the caller. I extracted the previous logic into a new helper:

```
public static class From<T> where T : INamespace
{
    [NotNull]
    public static string Select<TMember>([NotNull] Expression<Func<T, TMember>> selector)
    {
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
        var member = selector.ToMemberExpression().Member;
        return
            GetKeyFactory(member)
                .FirstOrDefault(Conditional.IsNotNull)
                ?.CreateKey(selector)
            ?? throw DynamicException.Create("KeyFactoryNotFound", $"Could not find key-factory on '{selector}'.");
    }

    [NotNull, ItemCanBeNull]
    private static IEnumerable<IKeyFactory> GetKeyFactory(MemberInfo member)
    {
        // Member's attribute has a higher priority and can override type's default factory.
        yield return member.GetCustomAttribute<KeyFactoryAttribute>();
        yield return member.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttribute<KeyFactoryAttribute>();
    }
}
```

that I use like this:

```
_features.Configure(From<IDemo>.Select(x => x.Greeting), o => o ^ Enabled);
```

It gets all information about how to create the name `Demo.Greeting` from an interface that needs to be properly decorated with.

```
namespace Features
{
    [TypeMemberKeyFactory]
    [RemoveInterfacePrefix]
    public interface IDemo : INamespace
    {
        object Greeting { get; }
    }
}
```

This unhides the default key-factory and also extracts the strategy of cleaning-type names into other attributes that can be chained and the user can provide his own logic anytime.

```
public class TypeMemberKeyFactoryAttribute : KeyFactoryAttribute
{
    public override string CreateKey(LambdaExpression keyExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = keyExpression.ToMemberExpression();
        var typeName = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType.ToPrettyString();
        typeName = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes<TypeNameCleanerAttribute>().Aggregate(typeName, (name, cleaner) => cleaner.Clean(name));
        return $"{typeName}.{memberExpression.Member.Name}";
    }
}
```

The new set of attributes are of the type `ITypeNameCleaner`:

```
public interface ITypeNameCleaner
{
    [NotNull]
    string Clean(string name);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public abstract class TypeNameCleanerAttribute : Attribute, ITypeNameCleaner
{
    public abstract string Clean(string name);
}

public class RemoveInterfacePrefixAttribute : TypeNameCleanerAttribute
{
    public override string Clean(string name)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(name, "^I", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

So, there are no more unsued parameters now and it looks like every part of it can be now customized.

Comment: This is a much better design. It feels right now :)