# Configure multiple application features by common criteria

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, expression-trees

My [`FeatureSerivce`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220938/toggle-any-application-feature-on-or-off) provides only basic APIs, so it is good in dealing with single features. Like I can configure only one feauture at a time:

> ```
> public FeatureService Configure(string name, Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure)
> ```

This might qiuckly get a lot of work when everything that has something to do with lets say `IO` should be disabled.

To simplify this task, I've created another set of extensions that evaluate features' tags and act accordingly.

A tag is an attribute that I use to set them:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TagAttribute : Attribute, IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly string[] _names;
    public TagAttribute(params string[] names) => _names = names;

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => _names.Cast<string>().GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

#### Example

```
namespace Features
{
    [TypeMemberKeyFactory]
    [RemoveInterfacePrefix]
    public interface IDemo : INamespace
    {
        object Greeting { get; }

        [Tag("io")]
        object ReadFile { get; }
    }

    [TypeMemberKeyFactory]
    [RemoveInterfacePrefix]
    public interface IDatabase : INamespace
    {
        [Tag("io")]
        object Commit { get; }
    }
}
```

Then I use a collection of features that I want to configure together based on some common criteria:

```
[Fact]
public void Can_configure_features_by_tags()
{
    var features = new FeatureService(Logger<FeatureService>.Null);

    var names = new[] { typeof(IDemo), typeof(IDatabase) }.GetFeatures("io").ToFeatureNames();
    features.Configure(names, o => o ^ Enabled);

    var bodyCounter = 0;
    var otherCounter = 0;
    features.Execute(From<IDemo>.Select(x => x.Greeting), () => bodyCounter++, () => otherCounter++);
    features.Execute(From<IDemo>.Select(x => x.ReadFile), () => bodyCounter++, () => otherCounter++);
    features.Execute(From<IDatabase>.Select(x => x.Commit), () => bodyCounter++, () => otherCounter++);

    Assert.Equal(1, bodyCounter);
    Assert.Equal(2, otherCounter);
}
```

#### Implementation

This is the set of extensions that drive this process. I separated them as much as it was possible so that each one of them takes care only of one *tiny* part.

Creating a feature name is a multistep process that works like this

- scan each feature-type and get its tags
- scan each feature-property and get its tags
- merge type's and property's tags together
- check if they match the criteria
- use feature-type and property to create a lambda-expression
- let the key-factory create names for each combination
- use created names to configure each feature

```
public static class FeatureServiceExtensions
{
    [NotNull]
    public static FeatureService Configure(this FeatureService features, IEnumerable<string> names, Func<FeatureOptions, FeatureOptions> configure)
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            features.Configure(name, configure);
        }

        return features;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ToFeatureNames(this IEnumerable<(Type Feature, PropertyInfo Property)> features, IKeyFactory keyFactory = default)
    {
        return
            from t in features
            // x.Member
            let l = Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Property(
                    Expression.Constant(null, t.Feature),
                    t.Property.Name
                )
            )
            select (keyFactory ?? KeyFactory.Default).CreateKey(l);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(Type Feature, PropertyInfo Property)> GetFeatures(this IEnumerable<Type> features, params string[] tags)
    {
        if (!tags.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("You need to specify at least one tag.");
        return features.GetFeatures(tags.AsEnumerable());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(Type Feature, PropertyInfo Property)> GetFeatures(this IEnumerable<Type> features, IEnumerable<string> tags)
    {
        tags = tags.Distinct(SoftString.Comparer);

        return
            from f in features
            let featureTags = f.GetTags()
            from p in f.GetProperties()
            let propertyTags = p.GetTags().Concat(featureTags).Distinct(SoftString.Comparer)
            where propertyTags.Matches(tags)
            select (f, p);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetTags(this MemberInfo member)
    {
        return member.GetCustomAttributes<TagAttribute>().SelectMany(t => t);
    }

    private static bool Matches(this IEnumerable<string> propertyTags, IEnumerable<string> otherTags)
    {
        return
            !otherTags
                .Except(propertyTags, SoftString.Comparer)
                .Any();
    }
}
```

---

I slighltly refactored the [`From<T>`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220984/59161) helper from my other question so that I can use the `KeyFactory` here and when creating them for multiple features:

```
public static class From<T> where T : INamespace
{
    [NotNull]
    public static string Select<TMember>([NotNull] Expression<Func<T, TMember>> selector)
    {
        return KeyFactory.Default.CreateKey(selector);
    }
}

public class KeyFactory : IKeyFactory
{
    [NotNull] public static readonly IKeyFactory Default = new KeyFactory();

    public string CreateKey(LambdaExpression selector)
    {
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
        var member = selector.ToMemberExpression().Member;
        return
            GetKeyFactory(member)
                .FirstOrDefault(Conditional.IsNotNull)
                ?.CreateKey(selector)
            ?? throw DynamicException.Create("KeyFactoryNotFound", $"Could not find key-factory on '{selector}'.");
    }

    [NotNull, ItemCanBeNull]
    private static IEnumerable<IKeyFactory> GetKeyFactory(MemberInfo member)
    {
        // Member's attribute has a higher priority and can override type's default factory.
        yield return member.GetCustomAttribute<KeyFactoryAttribute>();
        yield return member.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttribute<KeyFactoryAttribute>();
    }
}
```

---

#### Questions

Here's the example usage once again:

> ```
> var features = new FeatureService(Logger<FeatureService>.Null);
> var names = new[] { typeof(IDemo), typeof(IDatabase) }.GetFeatures("io").ToFeatureNames();
> features.Configure(names, o => o ^ Enabled);
> ```

- Would you say that this is easy to use and easily customizable?
- Have I separeted everything properly?
- Do you have an idea how I can better deal with `new[] { typeof(IDemo), typeof(IDatabase) }` as honestly, this part looks like it needs some improvement. Maybe a collection of all features? Mhmmmm...

Comment: This proof-of-concept is also on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.Tests.XUnit/src/FeatureService.cs).