# Toggle any application feature ON or OFF - follow-up (v2)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, thread-safety, extension-methods, framework

This is the second version of my `FeatureToggle` service (see [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220938/toggle-any-application-feature-on-or-off)). It still has the same purpose which is to help control whether a feature is `ON` or `OFF` and provide an alternative funtionality.

#### Changes

What is different in this version?

- I created a `FeatureIdentifier` that replaces the previous `string` *token* as a feature-key
- I created decorators for each of the features of the previous *god-class* `FeatureToggle`

  - `FeatureToggle` - executes `body` when a feature is `ON` or `fallback` when it's `OFF`
  - `FeatureToggler` - can automatically toggle between `ON/OFF` after each execution or only once with `ToggleOnce` option
  - `FeatureTelemetry` - logs feature statistics like execution time and whether its options are dirty
- I moved feature-options to the new `IFeatureOptionRepository` and created multiple decorators for new features

  - `FeatureOptionRepository` - stores feature options in a dictionary and saves feature-option changes by setting `Saved` flag and removing `Dirty`. I added `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to it because I'm using it with a web-service that toggles features at runtime based on the request
  - `FeatureOptionRepositoryDecorator` - simplifies creating decorators by providing default and overridable implementations
  - `FeatureOptionFallback` - provides default feature-option when the current one is `None`
  - `FeatureOptionLock` - prevents accidental feature-options changes

---

#### Core

The new `FeatureIdentifier` that currently has two properties `Name` and `Description` (this I might use later).

```
public class FeatureIdentifier : IEquatable<FeatureIdentifier>, IEquatable<string>
{
    public FeatureIdentifier([NotNull] string name)
    {
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    [AutoEqualityProperty]
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public override int GetHashCode() => AutoEquality<FeatureIdentifier>.Comparer.GetHashCode(this);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is FeatureIdentifier fn && Equals(fn);

    public bool Equals(FeatureIdentifier featureIdentifier) => AutoEquality<FeatureIdentifier>.Comparer.Equals(this, featureIdentifier);

    public bool Equals(string name) => Equals(this, new FeatureIdentifier(name));

    public static implicit operator FeatureIdentifier(string name) => new FeatureIdentifier(name);

    public static implicit operator FeatureIdentifier(Selector selector) => new FeatureIdentifier(selector.ToString());

    public static implicit operator string(FeatureIdentifier featureIdentifier) => featureIdentifier.ToString();
}
```

The `FeatureToggle` with its decorators:

```
public interface IFeatureToggle
{
    IFeatureOptionRepository Options { get; }

    Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task<T>> body, Func<Task<T>> fallback);
}

public class FeatureToggle : IFeatureToggle
{
    public FeatureToggle(IFeatureOptionRepository options)
    {
        Options = options;
    }

    public IFeatureOptionRepository Options { get; }

    public async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task<T>> body, Func<Task<T>> fallback)
    {
        // Not catching exceptions because the caller should handle them.

        return await (this.IsEnabled(name) ? body : fallback)().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public class FeatureToggler : IFeatureToggle
{
    private readonly IFeatureToggle _featureToggle;

    public FeatureToggler(IFeatureToggle featureToggle)
    {
        _featureToggle = featureToggle;
    }

    public IFeatureOptionRepository Options => _featureToggle.Options;

    public Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task<T>> body, Func<Task<T>> fallback)
    {
        try
        {
            return _featureToggle.ExecuteAsync(name, body, fallback);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Toggle))
            {
                Options.Toggle(name);
                if (Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.ToggleOnce))
                {
                    Options[name] = Options[name].RemoveFlag(FeatureOption.Toggle | FeatureOption.ToggleOnce);
                    Options.SaveChanges(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FeatureTelemetry : IFeatureToggle
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IFeatureToggle _featureToggle;

    public FeatureTelemetry(ILogger<FeatureTelemetry> logger, IFeatureToggle featureToggle)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _featureToggle = featureToggle;
    }

    public IFeatureOptionRepository Options => _featureToggle.Options;

    public async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task<T>> body, Func<Task<T>> fallback)
    {
        if (Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Telemetry))
        {
            using (_logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle(nameof(FeatureTelemetry)).AttachElapsed())
            {
                _logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Service().Meta(new { FeatureName = name }).Trace());

                if (_featureToggle.IsDirty(name))
                {
                    _logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Service().Meta(new { CustomFeatureOptions = _featureToggle.Options[name] }));
                }

                return await _featureToggle.ExecuteAsync(name, body, fallback);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return await _featureToggle.ExecuteAsync(name, body, fallback);
        }
    }
}
```

The `FeatureOptionRepository` with its decorators:

```
public interface IFeatureOptionRepository
{
    // Gets or sets feature options.
    [NotNull]
    FeatureOption this[FeatureIdentifier name] { get; set; }

    // Saves current options as default.
    void SaveChanges(FeatureIdentifier name = default);
}

public class FeatureOptionRepository : IFeatureOptionRepository
{
    private readonly Dictionary<FeatureIdentifier, FeatureOption> _options;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public FeatureOptionRepository()
    {
        _options = new Dictionary<FeatureIdentifier, FeatureOption>();
    }

    public FeatureOption this[FeatureIdentifier name]
    {
        get
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _options.TryGetValue(name, out var option) ? option : FeatureOption.None;
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _options[name] = value.RemoveFlag(FeatureOption.Saved).SetFlag(FeatureOption.Dirty);
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveChanges(FeatureIdentifier name = default)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            var names =
                name is null
                    ? _options.Keys.ToList() // <-- prevents collection-modified-exception 
                    : new List<FeatureIdentifier> { name };

            foreach (var n in names)
            {
                _options[n] = _options[n].RemoveFlag(FeatureOption.Dirty).SetFlag(FeatureOption.Saved);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class FeatureOptionRepositoryDecorator : IFeatureOptionRepository
{
    protected FeatureOptionRepositoryDecorator(IFeatureOptionRepository instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    protected IFeatureOptionRepository Instance { get; }

    public virtual FeatureOption this[FeatureIdentifier name]
    {
        get => Instance[name];
        set => Instance[name] = value;
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges(FeatureIdentifier name = default) => Instance.SaveChanges();
}

// Provides default feature-options if not already configured. 
public class FeatureOptionFallback : FeatureOptionRepositoryDecorator
{
    private readonly FeatureOption _defaultOption;

    public FeatureOptionFallback(IFeatureOptionRepository options, FeatureOption defaultOption) : base(options)
    {
        _defaultOption = defaultOption;
    }

    public override FeatureOption this[FeatureIdentifier name]
    {
        get => Instance[name] is var option && option == FeatureOption.None ? _defaultOption : option;
        set => Instance[name] = value;
    }

    public class Enabled : FeatureOptionFallback
    {
        public Enabled(IFeatureOptionRepository options, FeatureOption other = default)
            : base(options, FeatureOption.Enabled | (other ?? FeatureOption.None)) { }
    }
}

// Locks feature option setter.
public class FeatureOptionLock : FeatureOptionRepositoryDecorator
{
    public FeatureOptionLock(IFeatureOptionRepository options) : base(options) { }

    public override FeatureOption this[FeatureIdentifier name]
    {
        get => Instance[name];
        set
        {
            if (Instance[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Locked))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot set options for feature '{name}' because it's locked.");
            }

            Instance[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Helpers

The most common operations are made convenient with these extensions:

```
public static class FeatureServiceHelpers
{
    public static bool IsEnabled(this IFeatureToggle toggle, FeatureIdentifier name)
    {
        return toggle.Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Enabled);
    }

    public static bool IsLocked(this IFeatureToggle toggle, FeatureIdentifier name)
    {
        return toggle.Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Locked);
    }

    // Returns True if options are different from default.
    public static bool IsDirty(this IFeatureToggle toggle, FeatureIdentifier name)
    {
        return toggle.Options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Dirty);
    }

    #region Execute

    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(this IFeatureToggle features, FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task> body, Func<Task> fallback)
    {
        await features.ExecuteAsync<object>
        (
            name,
            () =>
            {
                body();
                return default;
            },
            () =>
            {
                fallback();
                return default;
            }
        );
    }

    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(this IFeatureToggle features, FeatureIdentifier name, Func<Task> body)
    {
        await features.ExecuteAsync(name, body, () => Task.FromResult<object>(default));
    }

    public static T Execute<T>(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name, Func<T> body, Func<T> fallback)
    {
        return
            featureToggle
                .ExecuteAsync
                (
                    name,
                    () => body().ToTask(),
                    () => fallback().ToTask()
                )
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
    }

    public static void Execute(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name, Action body, Action fallback)
    {
        featureToggle
            .ExecuteAsync<object>
            (
                name,
                () =>
                {
                    body();
                    return default;
                },
                () =>
                {
                    fallback();
                    return default;
                }
            )
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public static void Execute(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name, Action body)
    {
        featureToggle.Execute(name, body, () => { });
    }

    public static T Switch<T>(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name, T value, T fallback)
    {
        return featureToggle.Execute(name, () => value, () => fallback);
    }

    #endregion

    public static IFeatureOptionRepository Batch(this IFeatureOptionRepository options, IEnumerable<string> names, FeatureOption featureOption, BatchOption batchOption)
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            if (batchOption == BatchOption.Set)
            {
                options[name] = options[name].SetFlag(featureOption);
            }

            if (batchOption == BatchOption.Remove)
            {
                options[name] = options[name].RemoveFlag(featureOption);
            }
        }

        return options;
    }

    public static IFeatureToggle Toggle(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name)
    {
        featureToggle.Options.Toggle(name);
        return featureToggle;
    }

    public static IFeatureOptionRepository Toggle(this IFeatureOptionRepository options, FeatureIdentifier name)
    {
        options[name] =
            options[name].Contains(FeatureOption.Enabled)
                ? options[name].RemoveFlag(FeatureOption.Enabled)
                : options[name].SetFlag(FeatureOption.Enabled);

        return options;
    }

    public static IFeatureToggle EnableToggler(this IFeatureToggle featureToggle, FeatureIdentifier name, bool once = true)
    {
        featureToggle.Options[name] =
            featureToggle.Options[name]
                .SetFlag(FeatureOption.Toggle)
                .SetFlag(once ? FeatureOption.ToggleOnce : FeatureOption.None);

        return featureToggle;
    }
}

public class BatchOption : Option<BatchOption>
{
    public BatchOption(SoftString name, IImmutableSet<SoftString> values) : base(name, values) { }

    public static readonly BatchOption Set = CreateWithCallerName();

    public static readonly BatchOption Remove = CreateWithCallerName();
}
```

#### Options

These are the options that are currently supported:

```
public class FeatureOption : Option<FeatureOption>
{
    public FeatureOption(SoftString name, IImmutableSet<SoftString> values) : base(name, values) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that a feature is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Enabled = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that a warning should be logged when a feature is dirty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption WarnIfDirty = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that feature telemetry should be logged.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Telemetry = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that a feature should be toggled after each execution.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Toggle = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that a feature should be toggled only once.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption ToggleOnce = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that feature-options must not be changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Locked = CreateWithCallerName();

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that feature-options have been changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Dirty = CreateWithCallerName();

    // You use this to distinguish between FeatureOption.None which results in default-options.
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that feature-options have been saved.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly FeatureOption Saved = CreateWithCallerName();
}
```

#### Tests / Examples

The `FeatureToggle` can be used anywhere for anything. These two tests show how the `Switch` extension is used for efficient testing.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Can_configure_features_by_tags()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<FeatureOptionRepository>().As<IFeatureOptionRepository>();
        builder.RegisterDecorator<IFeatureOptionRepository>((context, parameters, instance) => new FeatureOptionFallback.Enabled(instance));

        var container = builder.Build();
        var options = container.Resolve<IFeatureOptionRepository>();

        var features = new FeatureToggle(options);

        var names =
            ImmutableList<Selector>
                .Empty
                .AddFrom<DemoFeatures>()
                .AddFrom<DatabaseFeatures>()
                .Where<TagsAttribute>("io")
                .Format();

        features.Options.Batch(names, FeatureOption.Enabled, BatchOption.Remove);
        features.Options.SaveChanges();

        Assert.True(features.Switch(DemoFeatures.Greeting, true, false));
        Assert.True(features.Switch(DemoFeatures.ReadFile, false, true));
        Assert.True(features.Switch(DatabaseFeatures.Commit, false, true));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Can_undo_feature_toggle()
    {
        var featureToggle = new FeatureToggle(new FeatureOptionRepository()).DecorateWith<IFeatureToggle>(instance => new FeatureToggler(instance));
        Assert.False(featureToggle.IsEnabled("test")); // it disabled by default
        featureToggle.EnableToggler("test"); // activate feature-toggler
        Assert.True(featureToggle.Switch("test", false, true)); // it's still disabled and will now switch
        Assert.True(featureToggle.IsEnabled("test")); // now it should be enabled
        Assert.True(featureToggle.Switch("test", true, false)); 
        Assert.True(featureToggle.Switch("test", true, false)); 
        Assert.True(featureToggle.IsEnabled("test")); // now it should be still be enabled because it was a one-time-switch
    }
```

---

#### Real-world example

I currently use the `FeatureToggle` in an email-seding web-service. So, in `Startup.cs` I register all components with `Autofac`:

> ```
> public class Startup
> {        
>     public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>     {
>         // ..
>
>         return
>             AutofacLifetimeScopeBuilder
>                 .From(services)
>                 .Configure(builder =>
>                 {
>                     builder
>                         .RegisterType<FeatureOptionRepository>()
>                         .As<IFeatureOptionRepository>()
>                         .SingleInstance();
>                     builder
>                         .RegisterDecorator<IFeatureOptionRepository>(
>                             (context, parameters, repository) => new FeatureOptionFallback.Enabled(repository, FeatureOption.Telemetry));
>                     builder
>                         .RegisterType<FeatureToggle>()
>                         .As<IFeatureToggle>()
>                         .SingleInstance();
>                     builder
>                         .RegisterDecorator<FeatureToggler, IFeatureToggle>();
>                     builder
>                         .RegisterDecorator<FeatureTelemetry, IFeatureToggle>();
>                 })
>                 .ToServiceProvider();
>     }
>
>     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
>     {
>         // ..
>     }
> }
> ```

APIs (actions) for sending emails are decorated with the `[SendEmail]` *filter*. It checks if the query-string `isDesignMode` was specified and if so, it then deactivates the feture `Features.SendEmail[GUID]` for this particular email because each email has a `GUID` that I can add to the name as an `[Index]`.

> ```
> public class SendEmail : ActionFilterAttribute
> {
>     private readonly ILogger _logger;
>     private readonly IFeatureToggle _featureToggle;
>
>     public SendEmail(ILogger<SendEmail> logger, IFeatureToggle featureToggle)
>     {
>         _logger = logger;
>         _featureToggle = featureToggle;
>     }
>
>     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
>     {
>         if (context.ActionArguments.Values.OfType<IEmail>().SingleOrDefault() is var email && !(email is null))
>         {
>             context.HttpContext.Items.SetItem(HttpContextItems.Email, email);
>             context.HttpContext.Items.SetItem(HttpContextItems.EmailTheme, email.Theme);
>
>             if (bool.TryParse(context.HttpContext.Request.Query[QueryStringNames.IsDesignMode].FirstOrDefault(), out var isDesignMode))
>             {
>                 if (isDesignMode)
>                 {
>                     // name: Features.SendEmail[GUID]
>                     _featureToggle.With(
>                         Features.SendEmail.Index(email.Id), f => f
>                             .Remove(FeatureOption.Enabled) // disable this feature for this email
>                             .Set(FeatureOption.Toggle) // enable toggle
>                             .Set(FeatureOption.ToggleOnce) //  toggle only once
>                             .Set(FeatureOption.ToggleReset) // reset options back to default
>                     );
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Finally, the middleware that does the actual job and sends emails, uses the `FeatureToglge` to either send it or leave it. `FeatureTelemetry` takes care logging and `FeatueOptionFallback` enables this feature by default for all emails.

> ```
> await _featureToggle.ExecuteAsync<IResource>
> (
>    name: Features.SendEmail.Index(email.Id),
>    body: async () => await _mailProvider.SendEmailAsync(smtpEmail, requestContext)
> );
> ```

---

#### Questions

I believe, I managed to implement most of your suggestions and like this version much better now. What do you think? Is this more future-proof, easier to use and extendable than before? Is there anything that still could be made better?

Comment: also on [github](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.Beaver/src) + [tests](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.Tests/src/Beaver/FeatureServiceTest.cs)

Comment: `public static implicit operator FeatureIdentifier(string name)`: when you provide this operator, haven't you then lost the benefits/strength that was the meaning by introducing `FeatureIdentifier`?

Comment: @HenrikHansen Mhmm maybe, but which ones? It's convenient to have this operator ;-) the benefit of having a comparer is still there.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I've added a real-world example.

Comment: mhmm... can anyone tell me which benefits/strenghts I am exactly loosing by using that aforementioned operator? It already has two votes but I'm still wondering what that might be ;-]

Comment: I give up. I cannot format the examples correctly. They are all broken, generics are missing, formatting is leaking, several lines of code are gone :-\ If anyone knows how to fix it, be my hero ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t - I have no idea why, but the "<--" in your C# comments appeared to be the reason the formatting was broken. I've removed them for you :)

Comment: @RobH thanks! This makes sense now as the generic arguments in the first snippet are gone too `.As()` it should be `.As<T>()`. I changed the formatting to use html element instead of backticks because of linebreaks and mixing `<` with html breaks everything. I'll need to escape this code...